# shell script not deleting files

Tags: bash, shell

I am using some shell script coding , here it is

```
DBHOSTNAME=********

DBUSERNAME=*****

DBPASSWORD=******

DBNAME=******

BACKUPFOLDER=$HOME/*******

DELETEFILES=Y

DAILYBACKUP=Y

NUMDAILYBACKUPS=2

WEEKLYBACKUP=Y

NUMWEEKLYBACKUPS=2

MONTHLYBACKUP=Y

NUMMONTHLYBACKUPS=2

TODATE=$(date +%d)
TOMORROW=`date +%d -d "1 day"`
TODAY=$(date +%a)
MONTH=$(date +%B)
WEEK=$(date +%U)

if [ $TODATE -gt $TOMORROW ] && [ "$MONTHLYBACKUP" == "Y" ]
then
    /usr/bin/mysqldump -h $DBHOSTNAME -u $DBUSERNAME -p$DBPASSWORD $DBNAME  | gzip > $BACKUPFOLDER/$DBNAME'_'`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`'_'$MONTH.sql.gz
else
    if [ "$TODAY" == "Sat" ] && [ "$WEEKLYBACKUP" == "Y" ]
    then
        /usr/bin/mysqldump -h $DBHOSTNAME -u $DBUSERNAME -p$DBPASSWORD $DBNAME  | gzip > $BACKUPFOLDER/$DBNAME'_'`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`'_'Week$WEEK.sql.gz
    else 
        if [ "$DAILYBACKUP" == "Y" ] 
        then
            /usr/bin/mysqldump -h $DBHOSTNAME -u $DBUSERNAME -p$DBPASSWORD $DBNAME  | gzip > $BACKUPFOLDER/$DBNAME'_'`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`'_'$TODAY.sql.gz
        fi
    fi
fi




if [ $DELETEFILES == Y ]
then
    NUMWEEKLY=$[$NUMWEEKLYBACKUPS*7]
    NUMMONTHLY=$[$NUMMONTHLYBACKUPS*31]
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*Sun.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMDAILYBACKUPS -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*Mon.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMDAILYBACKUPS -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*Tue.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMDAILYBACKUPS -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*Wed.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMDAILYBACKUPS -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*Thu.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMDAILYBACKUPS -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*Fri.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMDAILYBACKUPS -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*Sat.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMDAILYBACKUPS -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*Week*.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMWEEKLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*January.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*February.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*March.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*April.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*May.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*June.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*July.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*August.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*September.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*October.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*November.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
    find $BACKUPFOLDER/*December.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMMONTHLY -delete 2> /dev/null
fi
```

it is working fine, but doesnt delete old files, i  taken this from following address http://www.htpcbeginner.com/automatic-mysql-database-backup-on-godaddy/3/

what i need is backup of 3 days
like

Today files in folder
03/01/2017
04/01/2017
05/01/2017

and tommorow it should be 
04/01/2017
05/01/2017
06/01/2017

it should delete 3jan file

Comment: To start don't use double equal `==`, put only one equal `=`. Use double `[[` and `]]` on conditionals with more than one statement, I mean when you use `&&`. For example: `if [[ $TODATE -gt $TOMORROW ]] && [[ "$MONTHLYBACKUP" = "Y" ]]` or `if [[ $TODATE -gt $TOMORROW && "$MONTHLYBACKUP" = "Y" ]]` <- Thanks @chepner

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis If you choose to use `[[`, you can use `&&` inside a single command.

Comment: Use `$((...))` instead of `$[...]`. The latter has been deprecated for *decades*.

Comment: Yes you can too. Comment edited.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what the commenters have said, I think a key issue is your `find` command.  You have, for one example:

```
find $BACKUPFOLDER/*Sun.sql.gz -type f -mtime +$NUMDAILYBACKUPS -delete 2> /dev/null
```

But that should be

```
find "$BACKUPFOLDER" -name '*Sun.sql.gz' -type f -mtime "+$NUMDAILYBACKUPS" -delete
```

When using `find`, you list the paths (`"$BACKUPFOLDER"`) and the filenames (`-name '*Sun.sql.gz'`) separately.  You also *single-quote* the filenames to prevent the shell from expanding them.

While debugging, don't use `2> /dev/null`.  That discards error messages you might otherwise find helpful in solving your problem :) .

Comment: I had posted this as well, but technically the paths can be file names, not just directories. (In this case, you are letting the shell, via globbing, find most of the candidate files; `find` is simply filtering them by `mtime`).